# Fetch all the tweets containing a specific word from twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have used twitter api. I want to fetch tweets that contain a specific word for my application. like if a user types "iphone" then all the tweets containing that keyword should be fetched from twitter. How can i do it ? and should i use streaming api or the REST api? please help. The main reason for asking is the REST only gives the top 1500 tweets , but i need more. And the streaming gives real time tweets. so i don't know which one to use. or is there a way to get more then 1500 tweets using REST?

Comment: i can do it with REST api but it has the limitation problem so dont know what to do now.

Comment: @gordon actully i want to get more then 1500 tweets using REST... i dont know whether is  it possible to get or not.. if not then is there any alternative or not??

Comment: there is three alternatives listed in the dupe.

Comment: i dont get u?? where??? I am a student dont want to pay DATASIFT... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twitter API supports doing searches, by querying the `/search/tweets` endpoint.

[Reference documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets)

If you are worried about running into the API limit, then offload the calls to your client by making the calls via JSONP.

Comment: i have no idea aabout jsonp. can u give some reference or example?

Comment: @Julian is there a demo for this?